# Is there a way to output the numbers only from a python list?

Tags: python

Simple Question:

```
list_1 = [ 'asdada', 1, 123131.131, 'blaa adaraerada', 0.000001, 34.12451235265, 'stackoverflow is awesome' ]
```

I want to create a `list_2` such that it only contains the numbers:

```
list_2 = [ 1, 123131.131, 0.000001, 34.12451235265 ]
```

Is there simplistic way of doing this, or do I have to resort to checking the variable type of each list item and only output the numerical ones?

Comment: Why the heck is this question down-voted??

Comment: Darn it, this is when I wish I could chose two answers

Comment: and why is it upvoted so high now? it's a duplicate of many questions on here!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should be the most efficient and shortest in Python 2:

```
import operator
filter(operator.isNumberType, list_1)
```

This in Python 3:

```
import numbers
[x for x in list_1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)]
```

Comment: I don't use py3k, but then it will be just isinstance(x, numbers.Number) instead of operator.isNumberType)

Comment: ok.. I don't know much of python 3k, so I have changed the example again.

Answer (score 23):

List comprehensions.

```
list_2 = [num for num in list_1 if isinstance(num, (int,float))]
```

Comment: It may be worth adding the type long to your tuple.

Comment: To improve this, you can use operator.isNumberType to determine if an element is a number (see my other answer, to do this with filter instead of a list comprehension).

Answer (score 3):

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if isinstance(i, (int, float))]
```

Answer (score 2):

All solutions proposed work only if the numbers inside the list are already converted to the appropriate type (`int`, `float`).

I found myself with a list coming from the `fetchall` function of `sqlite3`. All elements there were formated as `str`, even if some of those elements were actually integers.

```
cur.execute('SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2 = ?', (some_condition, ))
list_of_tuples = cur.fetchall()
```

The equivalent from the question would be having something like:

```
list_1 = [ 'asdada', '1', '123131', 'blaa adaraerada', '0', '34', 'stackoverflow is awesome' ]
```

For such a case, in order to get a list with the integers only, this is the alternative I found:

```
list_of_numbers = []
for tup in list_of_tuples:
    try:
        list_of_numbers.append(int(tup[0]))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

**list_of_numbers** will contain only all integers from the initial list.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is:

```
[s for s in myList if s.isdigit()]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
filter(lambda n: isinstance(n, int), [1,2,"three"])
```

Comment: To test for various types:
filter(lambda n: isinstance(n, int) or isinstance(n, float), list_of_values)

Comment: i meant numbers in general and not just ints

Answer (score 0):

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if isinstance(i, (int, float))]
```

Comment: `isinstance` takes only 2 arguments.

Comment: Probably meant: list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if isinstance(i, (int, float))]

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> [ i for i in list_1 if not str(i).replace(" ","").isalpha() ]
[1, 123131.13099999999, 9.9999999999999995e-07, 34.124512352650001]
```

Answer (score -1):

for short of SilentGhost way

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if isinstance(i, (int, float))]
```

to

```
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if not isinstance(i, str)]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list_1 = [ 'asdada', 1, 123131.131, 'blaa adaraerada', 0.000001, 34.12451235265, 'stackoverflow is awesome' ]
```

first example:

```
list_2 = [x for x in list_1 if type(x) == int or type(x) == float ]
print(list_2)
```

second example:

```
list_2 = [x for x in list_1 if isinstance(x, (int, float)) ]
print(list_2)
```