# Filter a list in python get integers

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['Jack', 18, 'IM-101', 99.9]
```

How do I filter it to get only the integers from it??

I tried

```
map(int, x)
```

but it gives error.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int()
  with base 10: 'Jack'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>>> x = ['Jack', 18, 'IM-101', 99.9]
>>> [e for e in x if isinstance(e, int)]
[18]
```

Answer (score 6):

In case the list contains integers that are formatted as `str`, the `isinstance()` solutions would not work.

```
['Jack', '18', 'IM-101', '99.9']
```

I figured out the following alternative solution for that case:

```
list_of_numbers = []
for el in your_list:
    try:
        list_of_numbers.append(int(el))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

You can find more details about this solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39723833/5802289), containing a similar question.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, int), x)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Use list comprehension**

```
>>> t = ['Jack', 18, 'IM-101', 99.9]
>>> [x for x in t if type(x) == type(1)]
[18]
>>>
```

**map(int, x) throws an error**

map function applies int(t) on every element of x.

This throws an error because int('Jack') will throw an error.

[Edit:]

Also isinstance is purer way of checking that it is of type integer, as sukhbir says.

Comment: Some might argue that using `isinstance` is more explicit than comparing `type` s for equality. IMO it's a toss-up.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: No, issues. You are right. I just pulled a fast one. I just wanted to tell that list comprehension is the way to do it and also show him why using map throws an error.