# Removing white spaces and integers from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list in this format

```
['  PID', '    1', '    2', '    3', '    5', '    7', '    8', '    9', '   10', '   11', '   12', '   13', '   14', '   15', '   16', '   17', '   18', '   19', '   20', '   21', '   22', '   23', '   24', '   25', '   26', '   27', '   28', '   29', '   66', '   67', '   68', '   71', '   72', '   73', '   74', '   75', '   76', '   77', '   78', '   79', '   80', '  143', '  144', '  145', '  146', '  147', '  149', '  278', '  285', '  292', '  295', '  299', '  356', '  368', '  382', '  383', '  385', '  387', '  389', '  393', '  395', '  397', '  402', '  404', '  542', '  556', '  591', '  630', '  633', '']
```

I was wondering what I need to do to clean the list and just obtain the integers only.

I thought about just doing a loop that does an `int(value)` and `.isdigit()` check however this fails because of the `'   PID'` string at the start of the list.  I am wanting to have a clean list of all the integers.

I have seen this thread: [Filter a list in python get integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357832/filter-a-list-in-python-get-integers) however my situation is a bit different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is a list.

Comment: Assign the list to a variable (output) or anything and run this command.
`output = [x.strip() for x in output]`
That will cleanup the spaces.

Comment: What is the desired outcome? `['    1', '    2' ,...]` or `['1', '2',...]` or `[1, 2,...]` or...?

Comment: could there be float values?

Comment: Apologies for the wrong use of terminology of lists vs tuples.  I guess my desired outcome is [1, 2, 3, 4, ... ] and they're only positive integers, no floats.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because your items are contain whitespace. You can strip them then check if they are digits with `str.isdigit()` method.

```
In [2]: [item for item in lst if item.strip().isdigit()]
Out[2]: 
['    1',
 '    2',
 '    3',
 '    5',
 '    7',
  ...
]
```

If you want the result to be stripped as well:

```
[item for item in map(str.strip, lst) if item.isdigit()]
```

Comment: Why not `[item.strip() for item in lst...]`?

Comment: You can also note that `isdigit()` won't work for `float`s and negative `int`s

Comment: @TimPietzcker Because `C` is faster ;-) also you  don't have to call it in `if` condition too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this to removing the white space:

```
import re

for i in tuple:
    re.sub(" ", "", i)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kasramvd answer already deals with integers, if you wanted to deal with numeric values (+/- ints & +/- floats), you could do something like this:

```
int_values = ['  PID', '    1', '    2', '    3', '    5', '    7', '    8', '    9', '   10', '   11', '   12', '   13', '   14', '   15', '   16', '   17', '   18', '   19', '   20', '   21', '   22', '   23', '   24', '   25', '   26', '   27', '   28', '   29', '   66', '   67', '   68', '   71', '   72', '   73',
              '   74', '   75', '   76', '   77', '   78', '   79', '   80', '  143', '  144', '  145', '  146', '  147', '  149', '  278', '  285', '  292', '  295', '  299', '  356', '  368', '  382', '  383', '  385', '  387', '  389', '  393', '  395', '  397', '  402', '  404', '  542', '  556', '  591', '  630', '  633', '']
generic_numbers = ['     -0.5  ', ' 1',  '-2',   '        -3']

for values in [int_values, generic_numbers]:
    print('-' * 80)
    output = []
    for v in values:
        try:
            v = float(v)
            output.append(v)
        except:
            pass
    print(output)
```

Output would be:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0, 26.0, 27.0, 28.0, 29.0, 66.0, 67.0, 68.0, 71.0, 72.0, 73.0, 74.0, 75.0, 76.0, 77.0, 78.0, 79.0, 80.0, 143.0, 144.0, 145.0, 146.0, 147.0, 149.0, 278.0, 285.0, 292.0, 295.0, 299.0, 356.0, 368.0, 382.0, 383.0, 385.0, 387.0, 389.0, 393.0, 395.0, 397.0, 402.0, 404.0, 542.0, 556.0, 591.0, 630.0, 633.0]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[-0.5, 1.0, -2.0, -3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably the easiest way to do it and probably the best to understand if you havent done much coding. i shortened your list but it will work for your full one.

```
values = ['  PID', '    1', '    2', '    3', '    5', '    7', '    8', '    9', '   10', '   11']
for value in values: #runs through every value in yoour list
    value = value.replace(" ","") #replaces space with nothing, essentially deleting it
    print (value)
```

and the output is:

```
PID
1
2
3
5
7
8
9
10
11
```