# Make a list from another list in the most "python way"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started coding and I am stuck here.
Suppose I have a list:

```
arr=[["ashley",25,399.9],["tracey",26,990.45],["jimmy",23,987],["nancy",20,1000.1]]
```

I want all integer value in another list

```
age=[]
```

Comment: ["pythonic"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011078/what-does-pythonic-mean#:~:text=Pythonic%20means%20code%20that%20doesn,is%20intended%20to%20be%20used.) is the correct term.

Comment: Please show what you’ve tried so far and where you’ve gotten stuck.  What have you researched on this topic?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357842/2570277

Comment: Do you need to detect if the values are integers? Or are you just going to take the value in that position from each sub-list? Or what exactly is the rule that tells you what should go into `age`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [List Comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)

```
arr = [["ashley",25,399.9],["tracey",26,990.45],["jimmy",23,987],["nancy",20,1000.1]]

age = [v for i in arr for v in i if str(v).isnumeric()]

Out: [25, 26, 23, 987, 20]
```

This one is from @Leo Arad makes slightly faster:

```
age = [v for i in arr for v in i if isinstance(v, int)]

Out: [25, 26, 23, 987, 20]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that 987 is an age

Comment: LOL, definetly not but he mentioned "I want all integer value in another list"

Comment: You right probably that is the answer that part of the request

Comment: a suggestion for the if part `if isinstance(v, int)`

Comment: Yup, converting it into str for type checking is just making it lazier, i added your suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

yes you make

```py
arr=[["ashley",25,399.9],["tracey",26,990.45],["jimmy",23,987],["nancy",20,1000.1]]
age=[i[1] for i in arr]
```