# Sorting a list with strings and int. Only sorting int Python

Tags: python

Having trouble sorting a list with str and int. I want my code to return only listing int in asd and excluding str.

```py
def data(data_list):
   for i, n in enumerate(data_list):
      mn = min(range(i,len(data_list)), key=data_list.__getitem__)
      data_list[i], data_list[mn] = data_list[mn], n
    return data_list
data([8,11,10,9,4,3])
#returns this
[3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11] # which is great but when the list includes str it does not run 
#trying to run this 
data([8,11,'b',9,4,'a'])
# want to return this 
[3, 4, 8, 9]

#Also my code is quite confusing. I am sure there is a simpler way
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to output the numbers only from a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277914/is-there-a-way-to-output-the-numbers-only-from-a-python-list)

Comment: Make a list that only contains the integers, and then sort it. "I am sure there is a simpler way" The `sorted` function, and `sort` method of lists, are built-in. You do not need to implement sorting logic yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the built-in `sorted()` function and filter out items that are not integers using a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> datastr = [8, 11, 'b', 9, 4, 'a']
>>> sorted([v for v in datastr if isinstance(v, int)])
[4, 8, 9, 11]
```

Comment: is there a way to pull an int inside a string. 
so for example if the datastr= [8, 11, 'b', 9, 4, '2'] 
it will return 
[2, 4, 8, 9, 11]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance(i, int)` to check if a particular object is of type int.

```py
def data(data_list):
  return sorted([o for o in data_list if isinstance(o, int)])
```

If any on the numbers are strings, you can deal with them using a helper function like below

```py
def intHelper(o):
  if isinstance(o, int):
    return o
  elif isinstance(o, str):
    try:
      return int(o)
    except ValueError:
      return None
  
  return None

def data(data_list):
  return sorted([o for o in list(map(intHelper, data_list)) if o is not None])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = ['5',4,3,2,1.1,'zero','-1','0.4']
sorted_data = []
for datum in data:
    try:
        if isinstance(datum,str):
            if '.' in datum:
                sorted_data.append(float(datum))
            else:
                sorted_data.append(int(datum))
        else:
            if isinstance(datum,int):
                sorted_data.append(int(datum))
            else:
                sorted_data.append(float(datum))
    except:
        pass

sorted_data.sort()
print(sorted_data)
```